# Does it follow that $\{ (x,y) \in X\times X \mid d(x,y) < m \} \subseteq U$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space, let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $\Delta := \{ (x,y) \in X\times X \mid x=y \} $. Assume $m := \min\{d(x,y) \mid (x,y)\in\partial U \}$ exists (and thus is greater than zero). Does it then follow that $\{ (x,y) \in X\times X \mid d(x,y) < m \} \subseteq U$?

I drew a picture and it seems that it should follow. Since I haven't taken topology yet, I don't know how to approach such problems. A hint would be really appreciated.

Comment: @OpenBall: why?

Comment: I think you mean $m=\min \{d(p,q): p\in \Delta \land q\in \partial U\}$ where $d$ is a metric for $X^2.$

Comment: @user254665: I think I meant what it says now, i.e. $m := \min\{d(x,y) \mid (x,y)\in\partial U \}$. But I'm not too sure. Why?

Comment: I think you are right. Sorry.